# Laravel - Get checkbox value & update the database

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I am beginner in laravel and working on a room booking system. I have added the toggle button in each room list for Availability and Booking. Now, i want to get the checkbox value and save them in database.
[image]

```
<td>
    <label class="custom-toggle">
        <input type="checkbox" name="availability" id="availability">
        <span class="custom-toggle-slider rounded-circle"></span>
    </label>
</td>
```

I have `availability` column in `rooms` table. I want to save the `Available` and `Booked` value in db using ajax or any best method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can help you with that.

1. I think you can use ajax method as you are using toggle.
2. know used `onclick="roomTest('{{$id}}')"`

   `<input type="checkbox" name="availability" id="availability" onclick="roomTest('{{$id}}')">`

   - here $id is a room id.
3. now make a function for roomTest() in your js file.
4. I think you know laravel code and js for futher.
5. All Set enjoy Code (Please feel free if any other detail you want)